# State.data not updated in export function in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-props

I have a basic component that retrieves data from firebase database, and update the state object. I then try to pass the this.state.data to export function to view the data from the database, but it's throwing out undefined error for the data (as in there's nothing in the data).

```js
/**
========= LaunchScreen ==========
**/
export default class LaunchScreen extends PureComponent<*, State> {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
    this.personsRef = firbaseApp.database().ref().child('Persons');
    this.listenForPersons = this.listenForPersons.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => { this.listenForPersons(this.personsRef); };

  listenForPersons = (personsRef) => {
    personsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      var persons = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        persons.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          _key: child.key
        })
      });
      this.setState({data: persons});
    });
  };



  _renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    switch (route.key) {
      case '1':return ( <SimplePage state={this.state} /> );
      case '2': return ( <SimplePage state={this.state} /> );
      default: return null;
    }
  };

 
  render() {
    return (
        <TabViewAnimated renderScene={this._renderScene} />
    );
  }
}
```

**SimplePage**

```js
export default function CurrentStateIndicator({ state, style }: *) {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Current route is: {state.routes[state.index].title || state.index}</Text>
      </View>
    <List>
      <FlatList
        data={state.data}
        renderItem={({ person }) => (
          <ListItem
            title={person.name}
          />
        )}
      />
    </List>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But apparently, the state.data is undefined in SimplePage.

Can anyone please help me with how to pass the updated state.data to simplePage.

Thanks

Comment: Can you do `console.log(persons)` before `this.setState({data: persons});` and check if `persons` value is correct

Comment: Yes it does return an array of objects. @Jagrati

Comment: is state defined as an empty object? or is `undefined` being passed in as an arg? in the SimplePage function

Comment: @S.Nas
  listenForPersons = (personsRef) => {
    personsRef.onSnapshot( (snap) => {
      var persons = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        persons.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          _key: child.key
        })
      });
      this.setState({data: persons});
    });
  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  listenForPersons = (personsRef) => {
    personsRef.onSnapshot( (snap) => {
      var persons = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        persons.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          _key: child.key
        })
      });
      this.setState({data: persons});
    });
  };
```